# Дни недели без выходных

Tags: google-calendar

Построить список, содержащий все дни недели для любого месяца в любом году. Суббот и воскресений не должно быть в этом списке. Написать класс, содержащий методы, необходимые для построения такого списка.

Как теперь убрать сб и вс?

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Task5 extends AbstractTableModel{
  int column;
  int row;
  Integer days[][];
  Calendar calendar;
  String[] dayNames;
  int year;
  int month;

  public Task5(int year, int month){
    set(year, month);
  }

  public void set(int year, int month){
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    init();
    fireTableStructureChanged();
  }

  private void init(){
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7);
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    column = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 1;
    row = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) - calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) + 1;
    days = new Integer[row][column];
    dayNames = new String[column];
    int currDay = calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    String[] d = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortWeekdays();
    for(int i = 0; i < dayNames.length; i++){
      dayNames[i] = d[currDay];
      currDay++;
      if(currDay > calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
        currDay = calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    }   
    calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    for(int r = 0; r < row; r++){
      for(int c = 0; c < column; c++){
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month){
          days[r][c] = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        } else days[r][c] = null; 
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    return days[rowIndex][columnIndex];
  }

  public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex){
    return Integer.class;
  }

  public int getRowCount(){
    return row;
  }

  public int getColumnCount(){
    return column;
  }

  public String getColumnName(int columnIndex){
    return dayNames[columnIndex];
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Task5 model = new Task5(2013, Calendar.AUGUST);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам всего-то надо узнать какой день недели первое число месяца, а потом циклом от 1 до последнего числа месяца добавлять по пять дней к первому числу.
Для каждого дня в цикле нет смысла узнавать день недели.